# Clarification: Are runtime bounds in P decidable?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

In [Emanuele Viola](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/259/emanuele-viola)'s much upvoted [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/5006/35605) to the question, ["Are runtime bounds in **P** decidable?"](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/are-runtime-bounds-in-p-decidable-answer-no) he uses the following proof:

> The problem is undecidable. Specifically, you can reduce the halting problem to it as follows. Given an instance $(M,x)$ of the halting problem, construct a new machine $M'$ that works as follows: on inputs of length $n$, it simulates $M$ on $x$ for $n$ steps. If $M$ accepts, loop for $n^2$ steps and stop; otherwise loop for $n^3$ steps and stop.
>
> If $M$ halts on $x$ it does so in $t=O(1)$ steps, so the run time of $M'$ would be $O(n^2)$. If $M$ never halts then the run time of $M'$ is at least $n^3$.
>
> Hence you can decide if $M$ accepts $x$ by deciding if the run time of $M'$ is $O(n^2)$ or $O(n^3)$.

I have a significant problem with this proof, but as it is well accepted by theoreticians much smarter than me I am sure that I must be misunderstanding.

Here is my issue:

> $M'$ simulates $M$ on $x$ for $n$ steps.

If $M$ accepts, then $M$ certainly halts on $x$. However, if $M$ does not accept, this does not mean that $M$ does not halt on $x$; it only means that $M$ does not halt on $x$ in the first $n$ steps. In a comment, Emanuele clarifies that $M$ and $x$ are selected independently of $n$; however, this does not negate the fact that $M$ is only simulated on $x$ for $n$ steps.

So either this is a reduction from, "Does $(M,x)$ halt in $n$ steps?" which is a decidable problem, or I am missing some major component of this proof. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: If $M$ halts in $t$ steps, then $M'$ runs in time $n^2$ for all $n\geq t$, which is still $O(n^2)$. I.e. $t$ is some constant that depends on $M$ and is independent of $n$.

Comment: Actually, I see the same problem.  @SashoNikolov, are you sure that t and n are independent?  Doesn't t have to depend on both M and x?  Further, n is the length of x.  Perhaps I am also missing something.

Comment: @PhilipWhite : $\;\;\;$ t and n are independent because n is not constrained and if t is constrained, then it's to the number of steps M runs for on x. $\:$ t  probably does have to depend on both M and x. $\:$ If n is the length of x, then that's by coincidence. $\:$ ($M\hspace{.03 in}'$'s inputs certainly do not need to have the same length as x.) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer:  What are we calling the input to M' then?  I believed that "on inputs of length n, it [M'] simulates M on x for n steps" meant that M' is simulating M on the input of M' (i.e., "x").  My impression was that M' calls the UTM and simulates M on its input ("x") for |x| steps.  Is that a mistake?

Comment: @PhilipWhite : $\;\;\;$ We're not calling that anything. $\:$ Yes, since x is an entry of the reduction's input.

Comment: I think I understand what I was missing.  The trick is that M' is a whole separate machine that treats M and x as constants.  I.e., you start with an instance of the halting problem, and then construct a whole new machine *based on that instance*.  You don't necessarily even have to call the UTM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the wording of the answer is a little confusing.  Specifically:

> Given an instance $(M,x)$ of the halting problem, construct a new machine $M′$ that works as follows: on inputs of length $n$, it simulates $M$ on $x$ for n steps.

...confused me, too.  What you have to understand is that the machine $M'$ is based on *one specific instance* of the halting problem; it doesn't simulate $M$ on $x$ for $|x|$ steps.

Here is how I would word that part:

> Fix an instance $(M,x_1)$ of the halting problem.  Construct a machine $M'$ that takes as input $x_2$, and that works as follows:  simulate $M$ on $x_1$ for $|x_2|$ steps.  If $M$ halts within $|x_2|$ steps, loop for $|x_2|^2$ steps and stop; otherwise loop for $|x_2|^3$ steps and stop.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Since this is supposed to be for the halting problem, I would replace "accepts" with "halts". $\hspace{.52 in}$

Comment: So if $M$ halts on $x_1$ in $t$ steps, $M'$ takes $t+|x_2|^2$ steps for all $x_2$ such that $|x_2|>t$. Therefore, if $M$ halts on $x_1$, there exists some $N=t$ such that $M'$ takes fewer than $2*|x_2|^2$ steps for any input $x_2$ where $|x_2|\geq N$, so $M'$ is $O(n^2)$. If you add this to your answer, I will accept it as complete.

Comment: I made the edit.  @ Kittsil, Let me review that and make sure I agree.

Comment: I agree with what you wrote, but it might be better to let someone who is good at MathJax edit it or just leave it as a comment.