# Is any function between $n$ and $n\log n$ time-constructible on a 1-tape TM?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, time-hierarchy

##### The question:

Is there an $f$ in
$\omega(n) \cap o(n \log n)$
that is [time-constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function#Time-constructible_definitions) on a 1-tape DTM?

I.e. $f$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{f(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n \log n} = 0$?

##### Discussion:

Consider 1-tape deterministic TM's that take inputs of the form $1^n$.

It is easy to design such a TM with running time $\Theta(n)$:
just scan the input once.

It is easy to design such a TM with running time $\Theta(n\log n)$:
make repeated passes over the tape,
each pass replacing every other 1 with a 0,
and halting if the pass finds no 1's.

The question is, is there a TM whose asymptotic running time
$t(n)$ is strictly between these two?
That is, $t(n)$ is $\omega(n)$ but $o(n\log n)$?
Eg. $t(n) = \Theta(n\log \log n)$?

#### Answer (added in an edit):

The answer (posted below) is no.
The proof is an adaption of the proof of [a closely related result](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2009.08.031):
that any 1-tape TM that runs in $o(n\log n)$ time accepts a regular language.  The proof uses a crossing-sequence argument.

---

*[EDIT: This result was observed in Corollary 4.6 of the following paper:*

*Gajser, David*, [**Verifying time complexity of Turing machines**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2015.07.028), Theor. Comput. Sci. 600, 86-97 (2015). [ZBL1329.68111](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1329.68111).]

---

#### Context:

This question comes up in trying to answer another question,
namely, the complexity of deciding (for fixed $f$ and $g$ with $g(n) \not\in O(f(n)$) whether a given 1-tape TM $M$ that is promised to run in time $O(g(n))$ in fact runs in time $O(f(n))$).
Variants of this are considered [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5004/8237), [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12518/are-runtime-bounds-decidable-for-anything-nontrivial), and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/28056).
In the cases where $g(n) = O(f(n)\log n)$,
or when $f(n) = \Theta(n)$,
for 1-tape TM's this logarithmic gap presents an apparent obstacle to proving undecidability via diagonalization.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51084/48535) claims "*most functions that we deal with in practice turn out to be time constructible."*
On the other hand, it is not hard to see that there is no time-constructible function
in $\omega(1) \cap o(n)$, because, if a TM doesn't take more than $n_0$ steps given input $1^{n_0}$, then it doesn't look past the final input cell $n_0$, so, given any larger input, the TM also doesn't look past tape cell $n_0$, and its behavior must be the same as on input $1^{n_0}$.  So its run time never exceeds $O(\max_{n\le n_0} t(n)) = O(1)$ (where $t(n)$ is the run time on inputs of size $n$).

The [Gap Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_theorem#Gap_theorem) says that, for any function $f$ with $f(n)\ge n$, there is a $g$ such that $\textsf{DTIME}(g(n)) = \textsf{DTIME}(f(g(n))$, although if $g$ is required to be *time constructible*, the [Time Hierarchy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) says that
$\textsf{DTIME}(o(g(n))) \ne \textsf{DTIME}(g(n)\log n)$.

As Emil points out, it is easy to show that, e.g., $n\log\log n$ is time-constructible using *multi-tape* TMs, which as Chandra points out are usually the basis for definitions of space/time complexity, [especially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTIME#Machine_model) for low complexity classes.  Here the question is specifically about 1-tape TM's.

Comment: Just like cutting in half gets you a log factor, cutting down to sqrt should get you a log log factor.

Comment: But how to cut down to sqrt in one (linear time) pass, @JoshuaGrochow?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that - that's why I wrote it as a comment instead of an answer ;).

Comment: Don't we normally use multi-tape TMs when defining time/space complexity? Do you specifically want to restrict attention to 1-tape TMs?

Comment: Probably not important, but is the condition $f \in \omega(n)$ or $f \not \in O(n)$?

Comment: On a 2-tape TM, it's straightforward: using a binary counter, compute the binary representation of $n$ in one $O(n)$ pass over the input, compute the binary representation of $f(n)$ in time, say, $n^\epsilon$ for $\epsilon<1$ (any remotely sensible function you'd want to use as a time bound should be computable in subexponential time), and convert it back to unary in time $O(f(n))$.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri - I do specifically have in mind 1-tape TM's.  For multi-tape TM's I agree there is no issue, and I agree that it seems to be customary to use multi-tape TM's for defining time/space complexity , e.g. [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTIME#Machine_model) DTIME is usually defined w.r.t. multi-tape TMs.

Comment: @mathworker21, either would be okay.  The strongest positive result would have $f\in \omega(n)$, the strongest negative result would show there is no $f$ such that $f\not\in O(n)$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, yes, I just finished it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[EDIT: This result was already observed in Corollary 4.6 of the following paper:*

*Gajser, David*, [**Verifying time complexity of Turing machines**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2015.07.028), Theor. Comput. Sci. 600, 86-97 (2015). [ZBL1329.68111](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1329.68111).]

---

---

Theorem 3.3 in [1] shows that the language of any 1-tape $o(n\log n)$-time DTM is regular.
Adapting their proof gives the following negative answer to my question.
(I should note that [1] in turn adapted the proof of Theorem 3 of [2].)

Let $M$ be any 1-tape DTM.  Let $f(n)$ be its worst-case run time on inputs of length $n$.

**Lemma 1.** *If $f(n) = o(n\log n)$, then $f(n) = O(n)$.*

*Proof sketch.*
Assume that $f(n) = o(n\log n)$.
Apply the proof of Theorem 3.3 of [1] to $M$.
(Just to use the proof in [1],
assume WLOG that $L(M) = \Sigma^*$;
if not make it so by replacing
every undefined (i.e. halting)
transition in $M$ by a transition to
an accept state.)

For some constant $c_M$ depending only on $M$,
that proof shows that

> The length of any [crossing sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_sequence_(Turing_machines)) of $M$ for any input $x$ with $|x|\ge 2$ is at most $c_M$.

This immediately implies that, on any input of length $n$,
the number of steps that $M$ takes
with its tape head over the first $n-1$ tape cells
is $O(c_M n) = O(n)$.
To finish, we observe that the number of steps that $M$ takes
with its tape head over the remaining cells is $O(1)$.

Indeed, let $\mathcal X$
be the set of possible crossing sequences
that can occur between cells $n-1$ and $n$
in any execution of $M$ on any input.
Let $\Sigma$ be $M$'s tape alphabet.
Note that $|X|$ and $|\Sigma|$ are both $O(1)$, as $M$ is fixed
and every sequence in $X$ has length at most $c_M$.

For $(X, a) \in \mathcal X \times \Sigma$,
let $T(X, a)$
be the the time spent by $M$
over tape cells $n, n+1, n+2, \ldots$
given that
the crossing sequence between tape cells $n-1$ and $n$ is $X$,
and tape cell $n$ initially holds $a$ (that is, $x_n=a$).
Note that the behavior of $M$ beyond tape cell $n$
is fully determined by this $X$ and $a$,
and each $T(X, a)$ is finite because $M$ always terminates.

Then, on any input, the time spent by $M$
over tape cells $n+1, n+2, \ldots$
is at most
$\max_{(X, a) \in \mathcal X \times \Sigma } T(X, a)$.
This is $O(1)$, as the maximum
is over $O(1)$ values, each of which is $O(1)$.
$~~~~\Box$

**Remark.** I wonder whether the proof
(in particular, the proof of [1])
can be made to work assuming only $t(n) \ne O(n\log n)$.

---

[1] *Kobayashi, Kojiro*, [**On the structure of one-tape nondeterministic Turing machine time hierarchy**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(85)90165-3), Theor. Comput. Sci. 40, 175-193 (1985). [ZBL0603.68047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0603.68047).

[2] *Hennie, F. C.*, [**One-tape, off-line Turing machine computations**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(65)90399-2), Inform. and Control 8 (1965), 553-578 (1966); Russian translation in Probl. Mat. Logiki. Slozn. Algoritm. Klassy Vychisl. Funkcii, 223-248 (1970). [ZBL0231.02048](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0231.02048).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "otherwise just make every state an accepting state". Then the machine halts in time $t(n)=1$ on every input, doesn't it? And why do you actually need the assumption $L(M)=\Sigma^*$, anyway?

Comment: I don't see how "$M$ always terminates" should imply that $T(X,a)$ is finite for all $X$ and $a$. Surely it is possible that some pair $(X,a)$ cannot occur in any run of $M$? But anyway, this should not matter: simply take the maximum over those $T(X,a)$ that are finite. The infinite ones are irrelevant, as they cannot occur in the run of $M$ on any input $x$ (which is assumed to terminate, in $o(n\log n)$ steps).

Comment: Yes, good catch.  I had in mind that $\mathcal X$ should be the set of crossing sequences that can actually occur there for $M$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, re "make every state an accepting state", in the definition of TM that I am using (see e.g. Wikipedia) the TM halts when (and only when) the transition table of the TM doesn't have a suitable entry, and then (and only then) the input is accepted if the current state is an accept state.  I want every input to be in the language because the proof of Theorem 3.3 in [1] only considers inputs in $L(M)$ (although that assumption is not really used in the proof).

Comment: That’s a rather unusual convention. Usual definitions make the machine halt immediately after it enters an accepting (or rejecting, in formalisms that have them) state. The definition on Wikipedia, which ostensibly comes from Hopcroft and Ullman (I haven’t checked), requires exactly that: you must have missed the indicated domain of $\delta$, and the accompanying footnote. The definition in Sipser also works this way, though it differs in other details.

Comment: Indeed I did miss that.  I assumed that they were defining halting solely by not having a valid transition, and acceptance by halting _and_ being in an "accept" state.  Thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix it.